# Unable to pass intent.Extra from UserAdapter to c_Message_Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers){
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.student_item, parent, false);
        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final User user = mUsers.get(position);
        holder.std_name.setText(user.getName());

        if(user.getImage() != null && user.getImage().equals("default")){
            holder.std_profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }else{
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.std_profile_image);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, c_Message_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView std_name;
        public ImageView std_profile_image;

        public  ViewHolder(View itemview){
            super(itemview);

            std_name = itemview.findViewById(R.id.std_name);
            std_profile_image = itemview.findViewById(R.id.std_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity Code :

```
public class c_Message_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView s_profile_image;
    TextView s_profile_name;

    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c_message_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.c_chat_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        s_profile_image = findViewById(R.id.s_profile_image);
        s_profile_name = findViewById(R.id.s_profile_name);

        intent = getIntent();
        String userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");

        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                s_profile_name.setText(user.getName());

                if(user.getImage() != null && user.getImage().equals("default")){
                    s_profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }else {
                    Glide.with(c_Message_Activity.this).load(user.getImage()).into(s_profile_image);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can't pass my `intent.putExtra("userid",user.getId());` to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userid);`
Some can help me to solve this problem?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument
>   'pathString' in child()

Comment: check if your `user.getId()` contains any id or not. I think it's empty

Comment: may i know to check the user.getId() for empty or not? Toast.makeText?

Comment: put `Log.e("user_id", user.getId());` inside button click